# Construct mirror vector around the centre element in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I have a for-loop that is constructing a vector with 101 elements, using (let's call it equation 1) for the first half of the vector, with the centre element using equation 2, and the latter half being a mirror of the first half.

Like so,

```
double fc = 0.25
const double PI  = 3.1415926

// initialise vectors
int M = 50;
int N = 101;

std::vector<double> fltr;
fltr.resize(N);
std::vector<int> mArr;
mArr.resize(N);


// Creating vector mArr of 101 elements, going from -50 to +50
int count;
for(count = 0; count < N; count++)
        mArr[count] = count - M;

// using these elements, enter in to equations to form vector 'fltr'
int n;
for(n = 0; n < M+1; n++)

    // for elements 0 to 50 --> use equation 1
    fltr[n] = (sin((fc*mArr[n])-M))/((mArr[n]-M)*PI);

    // for element 51 --> use equation 2
    fltr[M] = fc/PI;
```

This part of the code works fine and does what I expect, but for elements 52 to 101, I would like to mirror around element 51 (the output value using equation)

For a basic example;

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  0.2  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

This is what I have so far, but it just outputs 0's as the elements:

```
for(n = N; n > M; n--){
            for(i = 0; n < M+1; i++)
                fltr[n] = fltr[i];
}
```

I feel like there is an easier way to mirror part of a vector but I'm not sure how.

I would expect the values to plot like this:
[image]

Comment: you mean that, you have a vector with M values, and you want to mirror the first half on the second half?

Comment: Why do you think you need a nested loop? Why do your 2 loops first decrement and then increment `n` but never change `i`? etc. Also, you should construct your `vector`s with their size, rather than constructing them empty and then `resize`ing. And declare your loop variables in the `for` rather than outside.

Comment: @underscore_d sorry it's a typo, the second loop increments i, not n

Comment: It's still not at all clear what you think a nested loop is doing here. You want a linear copy, just backwards. Why would you need 2 loops to achieve that? Anyway, as pointed out by Tanveer, there's a nicer way than manually looping.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't assign it in both ends as you calculate it? in the for loop you could just do fltr[n] = (sin.... ;  fltr[N-n-1] = fltr[n];  I think that'd be the easiest.

Comment: @Pzc ```fltr[n] = (sin((fc*mArr[n])-50))/((mArr[n]-50)*PI);
        fltr[M] = fc/PI;
        fltr[N-n-1] = fltr[n]``` this still gives 0 unfortunately

Comment: @underscore_d because I'm still mostly a rookie c++ programmer and I didn't know how to implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at your code:

```
for(n = N; n > M; n--)
    for(i = 0; n < M+1; i++)
        fltr[n] = fltr[i];
```

And lets make things shorter, N = 5, M = 3,
array is 1 2 3 0 0 and should become 1 2 3 2 1
We start your first outer loop with n = 3, pointing us to the first zero. Then, in the inner loop, we set i to 0 and call `fltr[3] = fltr[0]`, leaving us with the array as
1 2 3 1 0
We could now continue, but it should be obvious that this first assignment was useless. 
With this I want to give you a simple way how to go through your code and see what it actually does. You clearly had something different in mind. What should be clear is that we do need to assign every part of the second half once.

What your code does is for each value of `n` to change the value of `fltr[n]` M times, ending with setting it to `fltr[M]` in any case, regardless of what value `n` has. The result should be that all values in the second half of the array are now the same as the center, in my example it ends with
1 2 3 3 3

Note that there is also a direct error: starting with `n = N` and then accessing `fltr[n]`. `N` is out of bounds for an arry of size `N`.

To give you a very simple working solution:

```
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
    fltr[N-i-1] = fltr[i]; 
}
```

`N-i-1` is the mirrored address of i (i = 0 -> N-i-1 = 101-0-1 = 100, last valid address in an array with 101 entries).

Now, I saw several guys answering with a more elaborate code, but I thought that as a beginner, it might be beneficial for you to do this in a very simple manner.
Other than that, as @Pzc already said in the comments, you could do this assignment in the loop where the data is generated.

Another thing, with your code

```
for(n = 0; n < M+1; n++)

    // for elements 0 to 50 --> use equation 1
    fltr[n] = (sin((fc*mArr[n])-M))/((mArr[n]-M)*PI);

    // for element 51 --> use equation 2
    fltr[M] = fc/PI;
```

I have two issues:
First, the indentation makes it look like `fltr[M]=..` would be in the loop. Don't do that, not even if this should have been a mistake when you wrote the question and is not like this in the code. This will lead to errors in the future. Indentation is important. Using the auto-indentation of your IDE is an easy way to go. And try to use brackets, even if it is only one command.
Second, `n < M+1` as a condition includes the center. The center is located at adress 50, and 50 < 50+1. You haven't seen any problem as after the loop you overwrite it, but in a different situation, this can easily produce errors.

There are other small things I'd change, and I recommend that, when your code works, you post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232446/construct-mirror-vector-around-the-centre-element-in-c

Answer (score 3):

After you have inserted the middle element, you can get a reverse iterator to the mid point and copy that range back into the vector through `std::back_inserter`. The vector is named `vec` in the example.

```
auto rbeg = vec.rbegin(), rend = vec.rend();
++rbeg;

copy(rbeg, rend, back_inserter(vec));
```

Comment: so the `back_inserter(v)` function, would be using `n` not `v` in my case?

Comment: @Alex, your vector already has size `N`, you don't need `back_inserter`. Just write: `std::copy(fltr.begin(), fltr.begin() + M, fltr.rbegin());`

Comment: `back_inserter()` takes references to a container, it should be passed your vector where you want to insert new elements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `std::iota`, `std::transform`, and `std::copy` instead of raw loops:

```
const double fc = 0.25;
constexpr double PI = 3.1415926;

const std::size_t M = 50;
const std::size_t N = 2 * M + 1;

std::vector<double> mArr(M);
std::iota(mArr.rbegin(), mArr.rend(), 1.);    // = [M, M - 1, ..., 1]

const auto fn = [=](double m) { return std::sin((fc * m) + M) / ((m + M) * PI); };

std::vector<double> fltr(N);
std::transform(mArr.begin(), mArr.end(), fltr.begin(), fn);
fltr[M] = fc / PI;
std::copy(fltr.begin(), fltr.begin() + M, fltr.rbegin());
```